# Is it possible to cancel all notifications that have a certain tag?

Tags: android, mobile, notifications, notificationmanager

I'm making an android app and I would like to cancel all notifications that have a certain tag.

Right now it only seems possible to cancel notifications by their id (int id) or by both their ids and tags.

mNotificationManager.cancel(int id);

or

mNotificationManager.cancel(String tag, int id);

I want to be able to cancel all notifications of String tag regardless of int id.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it isn't.  The way Notification is set up, id is the primary key.  You can add a subkey with tag, and cancel an individual (tag, id) pair that way, but you can't cancel based on tag alone.  Really I'm not sure why they added a tag parameter, as it seems rather redundnt, except that possibly a string parameter makes for easier debugging.

Comment: Tags are very useful when you are developing an app with multiple components using notifications. If you set a tag for each component, you don't have to worry about the uniqueness of the ids in the context of all of the components. They just have to be unique locally.

Comment: @Nedko about which components you are talking? and can you give me code example of `tag` use?

Comment: @Gabe how `tag` could be useful for debugging purpose?

Answer (score 4):

Yes , it is possible

1. Get all active notification build by your app using `mNotificationManager.getActiveNotifications()`
2. Filter Notification based on TAG.
3. Cancel those notifications.

Try below code

```
void cancelGivenTagNotification(String tag){
    StatusBarNotification notiList[] = notificationManager.getActiveNotifications();
    for(int i=0;i<notiList.length;i++){
        if(notiList[i].getTag().equals(tag)){
            int notiId = notiList[i].getId();
            notificationManager.cancel(tag,notiId);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On Android using API >= 23 you can do something like this to remove a group of notifications:

```
for (StatusBarNotification statusBarNotification : mNotificationManager.getActiveNotifications()) {
    if (KEY_MESSAGE_GROUP.equals(statusBarNotification.getGroupKey())) {
        mNotificationManager.cancel(statusBarNotification.getId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems possible if you use notification groups. Cancelling the group summary notification seems to cancel the entire group.